# How do you make dummies for collinear categorical variables?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, multicollinearity

Suppose I have the following relationship

$$y = A + B + \epsilon$$

where $A$ is a categorical variable with $2$ levels and $B$ is categorical with $3$ levels. However when $A = 1$, $B=1$, always. How do I set up the dummies to fit a linear regression model?

Comment: This sounds like a case of measuring the same quantity twice but in different ways, something akin to measuring a distance in feet and then in meters.

Comment: I think we’d need more information to help you. What do these variables represent? Without more information, I would suggest dropping either A or B.

Comment: @Thomas These are *nested* variables.  Dropping one of them would be inadvisable.  What we ought to be considering is whether there is any problem at all with standard methods of dummy coding.  (There aren't.)

Comment: @whuber Of course. I was thinking about it too narrowly. I was imagining a situation where the OP was modeling, say, year *and* seasonal effects simultaneously.

Comment: In `R`, you can fit this model with `lm(y ~ A + B - 1, X)`, assuming the data frame `X` has variables named "A", "B", and "y".  The point is that your condition is not collinearity.